# How do I configure IMail to not accept invalid email?

Tags: email

I am installing a Spam filter and getting an error that says my mail server is accepting invalid email. My mail server is IMail Server 10.  Anyone know how to configure it to reject invalid email?

Answer (score 1):

By default is should not just blindly accept invalid emails. There are two things I can think off that could cause this issue.

1. A domain that has a "nobody" alias. This is a *.*@domain wildcard address that will pick up everything.
2. You have the setting to relay for IP set with an IP that is found in your windows host file that the To: matches. As imail doesn't know the usernames this domain has it will accept everything. We have a customer who runs their own mail server so we get a lot of emails to invalid accounts on their box that they then bounce, but Imail has to accept.

We urge our clients not to use the wildcard as it causes unneccessary spam to them. Our log is full of examples where we reject emails for addresses that don't exist.

In the past we used a spam filter that sat before imail so it accepted everything. This put huge demand checking virus/spam on all emails. Not we use declude that sits in the middle of imail. Imail now rejects invalid email addresses and we only check this.